# ng-keypress to call function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom-events, event-driven

I have send button and I click on that button I send text from input. I want also on enter keyboard to send that text. I try with two solutions and nothing..

You can find my code below:

**First Solution**

```
<div class="modal-footer">
                <input id="enterText" name="enterText" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
                       ng-model="modalInstanceController.showText" ng-keypress="keyEnter($event)">
                <br/>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="modalInstanceController.concatConversation()"
                        ng-keypress="$event.which === 13 && modalInstanceController.concatConversation()">Send
                </button>
        </div>
```

**Second solution**

With send button I call this function:

```
 $scope.modalInstanceController.concatConversation = function () {

            $scope.modalInstanceController.currentConversation.push({
                loggedUser: $scope.modalInstanceController.showText,
                user: 'typing...'
            });
            $scope.modalInstanceController.showText = "";

        };
```

I also try to call this function in `keyEnter` function:

```
$scope.modalInstanceController.keyEnter = function (keyEvent) {
            if (keyEvent.which === 13) {
                $scope.modalInstanceController.currentConversation.push({
                    loggedUser: $scope.modalInstanceController.showText,
                    user: 'typing...'
                });
                $scope.modalInstanceController.showText = "";
            }
        };

$scope.modalInstanceController.keyEnter();
```

And in html:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="modalInstanceController.concatConversation()"
                        ng-keypress="modalInstanceController.keyEnter($event)">Send
                </button>
```

I am getting error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'which' of undefined

Should I add something on dependency or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
if (keyEvent.keyCode === 13)
```

and one more thing

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="modalInstanceController.concatConversation()"
                        ng-keypress="$event.keyCode === 13 && modalInstanceController.concatConversation?modalInstanceController.concatConversation():''">Send
            </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am adding some of the major **concept of Events**.

1. If the browser supports event.which, then use event.which, otherwise use event.keyCode
2. event.keycode/event.which will read **which key strocked** and relative numeric value it will return.

you can test below code in javascript, just copy below code and try using it.

> <input type="text" onkeypress="init(event)">
>
> function init(event){
>
> var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
>
> alert(x);
>
> }

It is not about **ng-keypress**, just **which** is not responding value, it will depend upon browsers, for some value will come, So use code as above mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Just put form tag surrounded it

```
<div class="modal-footer">
<form>
                <input id="enterText" name="enterText" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
                       ng-model="modalInstanceController.showText" ng-keypress="keyEnter($event)">
                <br/>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="modalInstanceController.concatConversation()"
                        ng-keypress="$event.which === 13 && modalInstanceController.concatConversation()">Send
                </button>
</form>
        </div>
```